# Issue when implementing collection on grid object using Jackson

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

we are using spring jackson conversion for populating the jq grid, we are using an dto object to populate the grid. But when the dto object implements collection, we are experiencing a strange behaviour. Only the list are returned and it ignores other properties like count, pageSize etc. Please have a look at the dto class,

the TestDto class is,

```
public class TestDto<T> implements Serializable, Collection<T> {


    protected int count;


    protected int pageSize;



    protected Collection<T> datas;




    public TestDto(int count, int pageSize, Collection<T> datas) {
        this.datas = datas;
        this.count = count;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Collection<T> getDatas() {
        return datas;
    }


    /** overrided methods **/
}
```

In the client side, I am getting only the list of datas.
Other properties(count, pagesize) are ignored, when I removed the implements collection part, all properties are available on client side. But we need to implement the collection part

Could you please help me to fix the issue, is there any way to fix the issue using jacksonannotation

Regards
ST

Comment: What version of Jackson and Spring do you use?

Comment: I got a clue on this, I have an overrided method on implementing collection.  the method is public Iterator<T> iterator(), this method returs datas.iterator(), Any suggestions from your side? I think this is causing problem, any thoughts on this friends?

Comment: try to add _@JsonSerialize_ annotation on getter methods